# How to get Signer certificate from perticular host for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I want Signer certificate from specific host (ex: https://example.com:443
) and want to configure on Tomcat 8. I know the steps for SSL Configuration but this is different from SSL.

I am able to do this on IBM websphere using Admin Console with option like retrieve from Port. But Tomcat does not provide this facility.

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution for getting Signer certificate and it works for me.
I have followed following Steps:

1. Hit the URL in Mozilla Firefox (ex: https://example.com:443 )
2. You will get Green Lock Symbol, Click on that
3. Select First option, Secure Connection and Click on More information
4. Go to Security tab and then click on View Certificate
5. It will open New Window and in that select Details tab
6. Click on Export option and save on your System

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the root CA from any SSL port you can reach by running something like `openssl s_client -showcerts`

Here's a one-liner, that uses some GNU sed extensions (to grab the last cert printed by s_client):

```
printf "\x04" | \
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts | \
tac | \
sed -ne '/CERTIFICATE/{p; :loop n; p; /CERTIFICATE/q; b loop}' | \
tac > out.cer
```

You can also use the util here to retreive the signer from a port and add it to your JKS:

https://github.com/covener/plugin-tools/blob/master/retrievesigner.jar

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. But I am getting Null pointer exception using retrievesigner.jar file and no response from host using command.

But same host name and port works if i retrieve the signer certificate using IBM websphere Retrieve from port option.